# Negative Predicate in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I want to make a negative base case, that is, the rule should not work if the argument is an empty list.

\+fun([]).

One option is to put a "L =/ []" in every rule I write for fun(L), but having a single negative predicate would be nicer.

Comment: Why not define your rules for non-empty lists and not for the empty list? Then it will fail for empty lists. You should show an example rule for illustration. Also, `L =/ []` is incorrect. You mean `L \= []`.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want

```
fun([_|_]). % true if argument is a list of at least 1 element
```

Answer (score 0):

add *before* of every other `fun` clauses

```
fun([]) :- !, fail.
```